# how to detect contour without inclusion of surface irregularities and high curvature

Tags: image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

I wish to know if there is a way to detect a very smooth contour of this blob without including any surface irregularities (objects close or attached to the surface that tend to increase the curvature dramatically).

The approach that I have been using includes the use of `MorphologicalBinarize`. However, I do not know how to get rid of any irregularities close to the surface of the blob

[image]

Note: Since i have a stack of images, drawing by hand is tedious

Answer (score 8):

```
img00=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/unvja.png"]
```

[image]

```
img01=Erosion[img00,DiskMatrix[60]]
```

[image]

here is the result :

```
img02=Dilation[img01,DiskMatrix[60]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The value `60` used for Erosion/Dilation has been easily found by experimental trials (4 iterations : 3 -> 10 -> 30 -> 60) .

comparaison result/initial image :

```
img03=ImageMultiply @@ (ColorNegate /@ (GradientFilter[#,2]& /@  {img00,img02}))
```

[image]

Comment: `Erosion` followed by `Dilation` is known as [`Opening`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opening.html). If one wants to fill holes as well as remove protrusions, one can perform `Closing` as well.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. In fact my approach was "chimical" rather than "image processing".

Answer (score 5):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBF7C.png"];

curveImg = ColorNegate@CurvatureFlowFilter[img, 80];

circleImg = ColorNegate@EdgeDetect[FillingTransform[DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[curveImg]]]];

circleImgCol = Colorize[circleImg, ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> White}];

ImageMultiply[img, circleImgCol]
```

[image]