# Image processing: Removal of two spots in fundus images

Tags: image-processing

I have many hundreds fundus images of the human eye.

[image: Fundus image of human eye]

> The yellow arrow points to two spots which I I want to remove. The
>   final result should be  a perfect circle.
>
> The removed area should be black.

I need this for image preprocessing for a machine learning project.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 10):

Find the largest morphological component:

```
m = SelectComponents[MorphologicalComponents[img, 0.1], "Area", -1];
```

[image]

Get the bounding circle (with radius multiplied by 0.98 to remove the blips)

```
circ = Flatten[{#[[1]], .98 #[[2]]} & /@ 
    ComponentMeasurements[m, {"Centroid", "BoundingDiskRadius"}][[All,2]], 1];
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[circ[[1]], circ[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]

```
mask = Show[Image[ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[ImageData[img]]]], 
  Graphics[{White, Disk[circ[[1]], circ[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]

```
newimg = ImageMultiply[img, mask]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think it may be interesting to preprocess the image before using @Melago's approach.
   This permits to get rid of the `0.98` coefficient.

One may say that the following preprocessing introduces a new "magic" coefficient (`erosionRadius = 30`), but this new coefficient is less critical than the `0.98`.

```
img00 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUebf.jpg"]
```

[image]

```
img01 = MorphologicalBinarize[img00]
```

[image]

```
erosionRadius = 30;
img02 = Erosion[img01, DiskMatrix[erosionRadius], Padding -> 0]
```

[image]

```
m = Dilation[img02, DiskMatrix[erosionRadius]]
```

[image]

Note that the top and the bottom are slightly flattened. This should not have effect on the extracted "BoundingDiskRadius"

Beyong this point, @Melago's approach is used :

```
circ = Flatten[{#[[1]], (* 0.98 : Removed *) #[[2]]} & /@ 
    ComponentMeasurements[m, {"Centroid", "BoundingDiskRadius"}][[All,
       2]], 1];
Show[img00, Graphics[{Red,Thick,Circle[circ[[1]], circ[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]

[Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151247/5467)